# Read pretty-printed JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

Suppose that I have a file with a content like this one:

```
{
    "_id": 0,
    "metadata": {
        "feature1": "value1",
        "feature2": "value2",
    }
}
{
    "_id": 1,
    "metadata": {
        "feature1": "value3",
        "feature2": "value4",
    }
}
```

which was generated by pretty printing each JSON row of a database (notice that between each JSON "row", there is no comma, i.e. `}{` instead of `},{`).

How can I parse such a file to read it (hopefully in Pandas)?

Comment: Perhaps [`dirty-json`](https://pypi.org/project/dirtyjson/) would be helpful

Comment:  Ironically… ;)

Comment: I'll check it out @inspectorG4dget

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I have tested it with my example and it only retrieves the first element of the JSON. It seems that dirtyjson only reads one json at a time. The documentation doesn't show how to read a file with many json lines. Do you happen to know how to do this?

Comment: I'm no json expert. Just saw that package and thought it might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you will find no *magic* built-in way. JSON format is specified to contain one single object, even if that object can be a list.

A variant called JSONL allows one object per line. This variant is not accepted by the Standard Python Library json module, but is by Pandas `read_json`. Unfortunately, this variant does not allow multiline objects.

But you data is even worse, it contains commas (`,`) after the last field (a comma immediately before a closing brace (`}`)) which is rejected by all JSON processors.

That means that you will have to preprocess your data:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

with open('garbage_file.json') as fd:
    data = fd.read()       # loads everything in a multiple poorly formatted json string

data = re.sub(r'(?<!\n})\n', ' ', data)  # remove newlines unless preceded with a single } character
data = re.sub(r',\s*}', '}', data)       # remove offending comma before }

# ok, data should now be a correct JSONL string
df = pd.read_json(data, lines=True)
```